# Java Matrix Multiplication resulting in same matrix

Tags: java, matrix

Could someone perhaps help me with a problem I have? My brain is fried and I feel like im missing something dumb.

```
public static int [][] matMultiply(int[][] A, int [][] B) {
        int[][] result = new int[A.length][B[0].length];

        for(int i = 0;i<A.length;i++) {
            for(int x = 0;x<B[i].length;x++) {

                for(int u = 0;u<A[i].length - 2;u++) {
                    result[i][x] += A[i][u] * B[u][x];

                }

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I print the resulting Matrix it just gives me the value of the B Matrix,any help will be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your third for-loop. Why are you using u

```
int[][] result = new int[A.length][B[0].length];

        for(int i = 0;i<A.length;i++) {
            for(int x = 0;x<B[i].length;x++) {

                for(int u = 0;u<A[i].length;u++) {
                    result[i][x] += A[i][u] * B[u][x];
                }

            }
        }
```

This should produce expected results.

Comment: can you plz edit your post. your answer seems to be incomplete i tried to format but couldn't.